# LogoFAIL virus vulnerabilities

Tags: patch, vulnerability

So I recently saw this video talking about a vulnerability in Linux to a virus called LogoFAIL. https://youtu.be/2QFJLszvDwg?si=VN5nyFKOwqWTyIwa Does anyone know if there are any plans to patch this vulnerability in Linux or if a patch has already been released? My system is 6 years old and Dell no longer makes BIOS updates for it, so Ubuntu would be my primary defense against this thing.
THanks

Comment: Since this happens early in the boot process, Ubuntu (or any other Linux distro) can't possibly mitigate this. The only option is a BIOS/UEFI update.

Comment: I agree and as with most virus: you need to do something weird yourself to begin with. Like install from an infected ISO. Stick with the main 4: update asap, don't install software you do not use, use decent passwords, only install from trusted sources Do that and you will not get a virus.